# Need to update values in table which has caused trigger (Error 1442)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1442

I'm trying to update the values in table which has caused the trigger. I know the reason of the error, but i need solution how to do it. I need to update old value of product quantity if new.id = id in table which if it's already exists. I can't update it in trigger and in the stored function. I'v spent hours of thinking about solution, how can i do it?

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS insert_product_trigger;
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER insert_product_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF exists(select id_product from product where id_product = new.id_product) THEN
update product set quantity = quantity + new.quantity where id_product = new.id_product;
END IF;
END; //
delimiter ;
```

I need to **update** the old value of quantity if product **exists** (just add new quantity which is in insert to the old one) and cancel insert or **insert** it if **not**.

ERROR 1442 (HY000) at line 3: Can't update table 'product' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Answer (score 0):

If product has a unique or primary key forget the trigger and

```
insert into product(id,qty) values (x,y)
on duplicate key update qty = qty + y;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a trigger to do what you're trying to do. A trigger cannot stop a DML statement (in this case, an INSERT) from proceeding, which is what you seem to want to do here. Instead, you need to use the correct DML statement:

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT
  (ID_PRODUCT, QUANTITY)
VALUES
  (some_id_product, some_quantity)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE QUANTITY = QUANTITY + some_quantity
```